# set maximum item in one page html and display the rest in other page

Tags: javascript, html

This is my second question about html, I have 8 items at my page and I want to divide it to be 2 groups, so in one page display 4 items only and the rest in next page.

This is my html code

```
    </div><h1>Reggy Gallery</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="" id="my-gallery-container">
        <div class="item h200" data-order="31">

            <div class="img-85">
                <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

                <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum
                    et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”. 
                </P><a href = "E:\Jakarta 2\Belajar\gridview\indexDetail.html">read more</a>    
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item h200" data-order="30">
            <div class="img-85">
                <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

                <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum
                    et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
                </P>    
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item h200" data-order="29">
            <div class="img-85">
                <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

                <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum
                    et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
                </P>    
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item h200" data-order="28">
            <div class="img-85">
                <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

                <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum
                    et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
                </P>    
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item h200" data-order="27">
            <div class="img-85">
                <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

                <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum
                    et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
                </P>    
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item h200" data-order="26">
            <div class="img-85">
                <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

                <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum
                    et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
                </P>    
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item h200" data-order="25">
            <div class="img-85">
                <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

                <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum
                    et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
                </P>    
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item h200" data-order="24">
            <div class="img-85">
                <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">
            </div>
            <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum
                    et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
            </P>
        </div>




    </div>


</div>
</body>
```

And I want to make my page display only 4 of them and display the rest in next and also a navigator like google have (1 2 3 4 5) for navigate to the other page
[image]

can anyone help me? I hope I don't repost for this case. Thank you

Comment: Pagination is the word. Send only 4 results from the server and keep the record of how many results were send. Then get the next set of results on the next page

Comment: Is requirement to display only four `.item` elements?

Comment: @guest271314 for now only 4 item elements, mate

Comment: @SwarajGiri Thank you for your advice, mate

Answer (score 1):

You can use `css` `:nth-of-type()` selector with `4` as value, general siblings selector `~` followed by `.item` to select all `.item` elements following fourth `.item` element, set matched elements property `display` set to `none`

```
.item:nth-of-type(4) ~ .item {
  display:none;
}
```

```css
.item:nth-of-type(4) ~ .item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <h1>Reggy Gallery</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="" id="my-gallery-container">
      <div class="item h200" data-order="31">

        <div class="img-85">
          <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

          <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
          </p><a href="E:\Jakarta 2\Belajar\gridview\indexDetail.html">read more</a> 
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item h200" data-order="30">
        <div class="img-85">
          <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

          <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="item h200" data-order="29">
        <div class="img-85">
          <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

          <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="item h200" data-order="28">
        <div class="img-85">
          <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

          <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="item h200" data-order="27">
        <div class="img-85">
          <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

          <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="item h200" data-order="26">
        <div class="img-85">
          <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

          <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="item h200" data-order="25">
        <div class="img-85">
          <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">

          <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="item h200" data-order="24">
        <div class="img-85">
          <img src="images/Round David Michael Setyadarma.png">
        </div>
        <p class="parg">1 Qui habitat in protectione Altissimi, sub umbra Omnipotentis commorabitur. 2 Dicet Domino: “ Refugium meum et fortitudo mea, Deus meus, sperabo in eum ”.
        </p>
      </div>




    </div>


  </div>
```

Comment: It's work at snippet, but didn't work on my project, let me check first, maybe I did some mistake. 
But, I still confuse for the rest item that should be displayed at next page.

Thank you, mate